# How to Updata nested document in mongodb

Tags: android, database, mongodb, kotlin

```
{
    "userId": "Ldu9N8DTIjfUApMlLUhuwzxZszt1",
    "userName": "Fake Star",
    "userChats": [
        {
            "chatId": "Ldu9N8DTIjfUApMlLUhuwzxZszt1Jaz5seHjL0Nct0IdSgixRW9wM8s2",
            "sender": "Ldu9N8DTIjfUApMlLUhuwzxZszt1",
            "receiver": "Jaz5seHjL0Nct0IdSgixRW9wM8s2",
            "receiverPic": "receiverPic",
            "lastMessage": "lastMessagelastMessagelastMessage",
            "timeStamp": 100
        },
        {
            "chatId": "Ldu9N8DTIjfUApMlLUhuwzxZszt1Jaz5seHjL0Nct0IdSgixRW9wM8s2",
            "sender": "Ldu9N8DTIjfUApMlLUhuwzxZszt1",
            "receiver": "Jaz5seHjL0Nct0IdSgixRW9wM8s2",
            "receiverPic": "receiverPic",
            "lastMessage": "lastMessagelastMessagelastMessage",
            "timeStamp": 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

```
 override suspend fun insertChatDetail(chatDetail: ChatInfo) {

    val chatExists = userCollection.countDocuments(
        Document("_id", chatDetail.sender)
            .append("userChats.chatId", chatDetail.chatId)
    ) > 0

    if (chatExists) {
        println("debug Chat detail already exist, updating existing one")
        // Update the existing chat document with new information
        val updateDocument = Document("\$set", Document("userChats.$.chatId.timeStamp", chatDetail.timeStamp))
        userCollection.updateOne(Document("_id", chatDetail.sender), updateDocument)
    } else {
        println("debug Chat detail doesn't exist, creating new one")
        // Add the new chat to the userChats array
        val updateDocument = Document("\$push", Document("userChats", chatDetail))
        userCollection.updateOne(Document("_id", chatDetail.sender), updateDocument)
    }
}
```

here I have a document for one single user  , storing a chat detail in userchats  array fist time I inserted the value with **`timestamp`** 100 and the second time with 1000 , but I want it to  update the first value from 100 to 1000  , I don't want to recreate new document

Answer (score 0):

If the update is by index you can just put in the index in the update body:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{ _id: documentId },
{
  "$set": {
    "userChats.0.timeStamp": 1000
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VgnvsSf5YHA)

If you want to update by value you can use Mongo's [array filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters) to update a documents based on a condition, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{ _id: documentId },
{
  "$set": {
    "userChats.$[elem].timeStamp": 1000
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.timeStamp": 100
    }
  ]
})
```

This will update all elements in the array that match the condition.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l92WT7qdl1M)